# Find distinct count of group by user

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to solve this issue  in query @

for Ex :

```
id  ip 
1   1.2.3.3
2   1.2.3.3
3   1.23.42.2
4   4.4.2.1
```

I am looking for

```
ip        count    ids 
1.2.3.3   2       1,2 
1.23.42.2 1       3 
4.4.2.1   1       4
```

I have tried with query -

```
select count(id) ,ip , id from table group by ip ;
```

it not working . how to solve this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will do it:

```
SELECT ip, count(id) as count, group_concat(cast(id as char)) as ids
FROM table 
GROUP BY ip
```

Comment: Why did you write `cast(id as char)` instead of `id`?

Comment: @True Soft Well under phpMyAdmin i have a blob field for ids instead of a char so casting give the right result

Answer (score 0):

You want to select the IDs for the group as text column that will have text for example '1,2'
If that is the case, you'd have to go along the way of traversing all results of

```
select ip, count(id) from table group by id
```

by a cursor that remembers @ip and @count, then for each row retrieve all IDs for that group

```
select id from table where ip = @ip
```

traversing all results by another cursor and store results inside nvarchar @ids variable that will look like '1,2'

then in the main cursor loop you'd output each row as 
@ip, @count, @ids

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL function [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select ip, count(id) as count, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids
from table 
group by ip ;
```